# JAF Bernini Sans analog with cyrillic

Tags: font-recommendation, sans-serif

I write large techincal documents and I am in search of a font for them. These documents sometimes need to be written in Russian, so the font should contain cyrillic letters.

I have discoverd JAF Bernini Sans and it is really gorgeous, but unfortunatelly doesn't support cyrillic.

Could anyone suggest something similar to Bernini Sans, but with cyrillic characters?